# XQuery/XPath: How to count occurrences of a specific value in different elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am trying to write a query which returns which author/editor occurs the most across the two separate elements ("redaktør" (editor) and "forfatter"(author)). E.g. below I have included two bok-elements from my XML. The author Simon Gray occurs twice, once as an author and once as an editor, while Michael Brundage only occurs once (as an author). From this XML the result should be Simon Gray.

I have the following query so far:

```
let $xml := doc('../Fagboker.xml')
return
(
   for $name in ($xml//forfatter)
   order by count($xml//forfatter[. = $name]) descending
   return 
        <x>{$name}</x>
 )[1]
```

This only returns what author has occurred the most. I need to extend this to count editors as well. I have tried queries such as:

```
let $xml := doc('../Fagboker.xml')
return
(
for $name in ($xml//forfatter)
    order by count($xml[. = $name] and $xml/*[parent::bok[child::redaktør]]) descending
return <x>{$name}</x>
)[1]
```

To no avail. Do I need to rewrite this entirely, or is there a way to include "redaktør"?

```
<fagbøker>
<bok isbn="9780321392794">
    <tittel>Data Structures in Java: From Abstract Data Types to the Java Collections
        Framework</tittel>
    <forfatter>
        <fornavn>Simon</fornavn>
        <etternavn>Gray</etternavn>
    </forfatter>
    <utgivelsesår>2006</utgivelsesår>

    <utgavenr>1</utgavenr>
    <fagfelt>
        <felt>Programmering</felt>
    </fagfelt>
    <referanser>
        <tittel/>
    </referanser>
    <forlag>Pearson</forlag>
    <TOC>
        <komponent>Part 1: Intro <komponent>Chapter 1: Hei <komponent>Subchapter 1 </komponent>
            </komponent>
        </komponent>
    </TOC>
</bok>

<bok isbn="0321165810">
    <tittel>XQuery: The XML Query Language</tittel>
    <forfatter>
        <fornavn>Brundage</fornavn>
        <etternavn>Michael</etternavn>
    </forfatter>
    <redaktør>
        <fornavn>Simon</fornavn>
        <etternavn>Gray</etternavn>
    </redaktør>
    <utgivelsesår>2004</utgivelsesår>
    <utgavenr>1</utgavenr>
    <fagfelt>
        <felt>XML</felt>
        <felt>Databaser</felt>
    </fagfelt>
    <referanser>
        <tittel/>
    </referanser>
    <forlag>Addison-Wesley Professional</forlag>
    <TOC>
        <komponent>Part 1: Intro <komponent>Chapter 1: Hei <komponent>XPath
                        <komponent> </komponent>
                </komponent>
            </komponent>
        </komponent>
    </TOC>
</bok>
</fagbøker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use union (`|`) operator to select both `forfatter` and `redaktør` in one XPath :

```
let $xml := doc('../Fagboker.xml')
return
(
    for $name in distinct-values(/fagbøker/bok/*[self::forfatter|self::redaktør])
    let $count := count(/fagbøker/bok/*[self::forfatter|self::redaktør][. eq $name])
    order by $count descending
    return <x>{$name}</x>
)[1]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/R2XKFB3ae)</kbd>**